# "TypeError: dispatch is not a function" when using useReducer/useContext and React-Testing-Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm having issues testing my components that use dispatch via useReducer with React-testing-library.

I created a less complex example to try to boil down what is going on and that is still having the same `dispatch is not a function` problem. When I run my tests, I am getting this error:

```
      11 |         data-testid="jared-test-button"
      12 |         onClick={() => {
    > 13 |           dispatch({ type: 'SWITCH' })
         |           ^
      14 |         }}
      15 |       >
      16 |         Click Me
```

Also, if I do a `console.log(typeof dispatch)` inside `RandomButton`, and I click on the button the output says `function`.

Here is the test in question.

```
import React from 'react'
import RandomButton from '../RandomButton'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('Button Render', () => {
  it('click button', () => {
    const { getByTestId, queryByText } = render(<RandomButton />)

    expect(getByTestId('jared-test-button')).toBeInTheDocument()
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('jared-test-button'))
    expect(queryByText('My name is frog')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Here is my relevant code:

RandomButton.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import MyContext from 'contexts/MyContext'

const RandomButton = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(MyContext)

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        data-testid="jared-test-button"
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({ type: 'SWITCH' })
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RandomButton
```

MyApp.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import {myreducer} from './MyFunctions'
import MyContext from 'contexts/MyContext'
import RandomButton from './RandomButton'

  const initialState = {
    blue: false,
  }
  const [{ blue },dispatch] = useReducer(myreducer, initialState)


return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>
      <div>
            {blue && <div>My name is frog</div>}
            <RandomButton />
    </div>
    </MyContext.Provider>
)

export default MyApp
```

MyFunctions.js

```
export const myreducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SWITCH':
      return { ...state, blue: !state.blue }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

MyContext.js

```
import React from 'react'

const MyContext = React.createContext({})

export default MyContext
```

It is probably something stupid that I am missing, but after reading the docs and looking at other examples online I'm not seeing the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tested redux hooks with react-testing-library, but I do know you'll have to provide a wrapper to the render function that provides the Provider with dispatch function.

Here's an example I use to test components connected to a redux store:

> testUtils.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reducer from '../reducers';

// https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux
export const renderWithRedux = (
  ui,
  { initialState, store = createStore(reducer, initialState) } = {},
  options,
) => ({
  ...render(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>, options),
  store,
});
```

So, based upon what you've shared I think the wrapper you'd want would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import MyContext from 'contexts/MyContext';

// export so you can test that it was called with specific arguments
export dispatchMock = jest.fn();

export ProviderWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  // place your mock dispatch function in the provider
  <MyContext.Provider value={{ dispatch: dispatchMock }}>
    {children}
  </MyContext.Provider>
);
```

and in your test:

```
import React from 'react';
import RandomButton from '../RandomButton';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ProviderWrapper, dispatchMock } from './testUtils';

describe('Button Render', () => {
  it('click button', () => {
    const { getByTestId, queryByText } = render(
      <RandomButton />,
      { wrapper: ProviderWrapper }, // Specify your wrapper here
    );

    expect(getByTestId('jared-test-button')).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('jared-test-button'));
    // expect(queryByText('My name is frog')).toBeInTheDocument(); // won't work since this text is part of the parent component

    // If you wanted to test that the dispatch was called correctly
    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'SWITCH' });
  })
})
```

Like I said, I've not had to specifically test redux hooks but I believe this should get you to a good place.

Comment: Thanks for the response Drew, but I am not using Redux. I'm using the built in useReducer hook in React.

Comment: Yes @Jared, that was merely an example of a wrapper/provider I use in testing. Further in my answer I shared a wrapper I think you can use that mocks a `dispatch` function for your component under test. The actions/reducers used by both redux and `useReducer` hook are nearly identical.

Comment: Ahh pardon my ignorance, I'm not the most familiar with Redux. I thought the second part was still related to Redux. I see what you are saying now.

Comment: Sure, no problem at all. If anything is still unclear or you're still struggling I can try to provide more details or get a working code sandbox demo up.

Comment: I got what you said running in my project. It is no longer saying dispatch isn't a function.

So in this case since we are mocking the dispatch, it won't actually toggle and display the "My name is frog" text?

This line fails in my test, i believe since we are mocking it with a `jest.fn()` call.

```expect(queryByText('My name is frog')).toBeInTheDocument();```

Comment: @Jared For the `RandomButton` component? No, `blue` and the div with that text are part of your `MyApp` component. This is why I shared how to test that your button component correctly called "dispatch" with the argument you expected since this is all the button does.

Comment: Yeap, I just wanted to confirm. It can't find the changed div text because it is apart of the parent. If i wanted to see that showing up, I would need to test the parent component, instead of the child which is just a button. Thanks for your help, I think i'm getting it.